# Call same AJAX function from multiple forms on same page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX form in the footer section of my website that accepts e-mail subscriptions. The form has two fields -- email and country -- and works perfectly.

[image]

I've now added a link ("E-mail Updates") at the top of the same page that launches a dialog box with this same form.

[image]

I'm using an ID (`#footer-form`) to bind the footer form to the AJAX function.

I understand that an ID can be used only once per page, so I'm wondering how to bind the second form to the same AJAX function.

Should I use a class instead? Is there a way to bind multiple IDs?

Again, I'm hoping to use the same function for the same form where it may appear.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here's the jQuery for the footer form.

```
$(function() {

    // gets the form
    // how could I use this functions for multiple forms?  
    var form = $('#footer-form');

    // display responses to user
    var formMessages = $('#footer-form-messages');

    // set up event listener for contact form
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // disable html submit button
        e.preventDefault();

        // serialize form data
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // submit form using AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            // make sure formMessages element has 'success' class
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // set message text
            $(formMessages).text('Subscription complete.');

            // clear form
            $('#site-signup-email').val('');
            $('#site-signup-country').val('');
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            // make sure formMessages element has 'error' class
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            // set the message text
            $(formMessages).text('Error. Review and re-submit.');
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: i think this wont work this way. you have to use `$(this)`for the submit, if you want to make it work with more than one form.

Comment: Use a "regular" (named) function to handle asubmit event and attach it to both forms

Comment: Can include `html` of _"E-mail Updates"_ at Question ?

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
$(function() {
    // display responses to user
    var formMessages = $('#footer-form-messages');

    // set up event listener for contact form
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        // disable html submit button
        e.preventDefault();

        // serialize form data
        var formData = $(this).serialize();

        // submit form using AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            // make sure formMessages element has 'success' class
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // set message text
            $(formMessages).text('Subscription complete.');

            // clear form
            $('#site-signup-email').val('');
            $('#site-signup-country').val('');
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            // make sure formMessages element has 'error' class
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            // set the message text
            $(formMessages).text('Error. Review and re-submit.');
        });
    });
 });
```

not tested, but you get the message i guess.

you showed no code about `#site-signup-email` and other inputs, but you should be able to read them relative to `$(this)`, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a class will be the most apropiated and change

```
 var form = $('#footer-form');
```

to

```
 var form = $('.footer-form');
```

then inside the form referencing the form id whit the class like this should work

```
 $('.footer-form #site-signup-email').val('');
```

***I have not tested it

Comment: the class whithout the dot sorry :D